# Difference in deploying Appengine standard project via Maven vs Google Cloud Tools Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tools

I'm trying to deploy a project to App Engine, though i'm encountering a problem. The main problem is that a nosuchmethod error occurs when running a cronjob when the project is deployed through the Appengine maven plugin. The deployment is fine and without errors.

The following command is used for the deployment:

```
mvn appengine:deploy -Dapp.deploy.version=version-number  
-Dapp.deploy.project=project-name
```

The configuration for the appengine maven plugin is as follows:

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- deploy configuration -->
        <devserver.port>8888</devserver.port>
      <stage.enableJarClasses>false</stage.enableJarClasses> 
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

The weird thing is, is that this problem doesn't occur when i'm deploying through the Google Cloud Tools GUI in Eclipse:

https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/deploying

I am suspecting that there is some difference between the two methods, and I wonder what this difference might be?

The end goal of this, is to eventually deploy via Jenkins. So therefore deploying trough the GUI is not a long term solution.

I hope you guys can help me out!

Edit:
This is my current maven pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>name</groupId>
  <artifactId>name</artifactId>
  <version>123456-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>war</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>endpoints-framework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- plugin configuration -->
        <hostname>${endpoints.project.id}.appspot.com</hostname>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-rc5</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- deploy configuration -->
        <devserver.port>8888</devserver.port>
      <stage.enableJarClasses>false</stage.enableJarClasses> 
    </configuration>
</plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
 <dependencies>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk -->
<!--          <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-endpoints</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.54</version>
</dependency> -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
    <artifactId>endpoints-framework</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.13</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client -->
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency> 

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency> 

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-sheets -->
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-sheets</artifactId>
    <version>v4-rev478-1.22.0</version>
</dependency> 

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-drive -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
    <version>v2-rev247-1.22.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-storage -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-storage</artifactId>
    <version>v1-rev62-1.21.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-plus -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-plus</artifactId>
    <version>v1-rev456-1.22.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.http-client/google-http-client-appengine -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client-appengine</artifactId>
    <version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
 <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency> 

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
 <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency> 

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.1</version>
</dependency> 

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
 <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.37</version>
</dependency> 


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-client-appengine</artifactId>
  <version>1.21.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-client-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>1.21.0</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>


</project>
```

Edit, stacktrace:

```
com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyLogger warn: Error for /exportiati (JettyLogger.java:29)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: nl.icco.program.Program.exportIATI(Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter;Ljava/lang/String;Lnl/icco/indicator/IndicatorDefList;Lnl/icco/indicator/ResultDefList;Lnl/icco/company/Company;Lnl/icco/company/ExportChannelsPref;Lnl/icco/database/Database;)V
    at nl.icco.exporter.IATIexporter.write(IATIexporter.java:214)
    at nl.icco.exporter.IATIexporter.<init>(IATIexporter.java:121)
    at nl.icco.cronjobs.ExportIATI.doPost(ExportIATI.java:40)
    at nl.icco.cronjobs.ExportIATI.doGet(ExportIATI.java:16)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1772)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.ParseBlobUploadHandler.handle(ParseBlobUploadHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1182)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.doHandle(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:333)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnection.handle(RpcConnection.java:202)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnector.serviceRequest(RpcConnector.java:81)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:123)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:699)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:661)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:631)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:825)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:273)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: could you tell us more about the nosuchmethod error?  Does that come with a Java stacktrace?

Comment: Yes, the stacktrace is now included. An other direction I was thinking in, was that there is a duplicate library defined. But I couldn't figure this out.

Comment: it does seem likely that the difference between the two deployments is in the classpath.  You may want to review the list of dependencies in your pom.xml versus your Eclipse project.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this error may be due to the fact that the `mvn appengine:deploy` command doesn't upload additional configuration files like `cron.yaml` or `dispatch.yaml` (unlike the Cloud Tools plugin and its "Include optional App Engine configuration files" checkbox on deployment screen).

You may want to issue additional command like `mvn appengine:deployDispatch`, `mvn appengine:deployCron` or even use the `appengine:deployAll` goal mentioned [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin/tree/8b1e13f356bbffa005f69d5abde328a99b6494fb#supported-goals). If you'd rather issue all those commands at once, please also have a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45551076/4926605).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it didn't work. I updated the maven plugin to 2.0.0-rc5 and redeployed with `mvn appengine:deployAll`, but it didn't make any difference. Do you have any other suggestions maybe?